# Input numbers from a text file to an ArrayList while counting the occurrances of each number

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

A text file contains a list of 1000 numbers that range from 1 to 100.  I need to use an arrayList to store all the integers.  If an integer appears multiple times in the text file, only save the first occurrence in the arrayList. Then, I need to create an output file that tells the user how many times each number occurred in the file.  So far I have the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io*;  
public class HW4
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      FileReader file = new FileReader("numbers.txt");
      ArrayList<int> intList = new Arraylist<int>(1000);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         intList.add(inputFile.nextLine());
      }
      intList.close();
   }
}
```

So far, I have declared the filereader and the arrayList as well as the scanner.  The while loop will add the numbers from the text file to the array but I need help figuring out how to make sure each number is only stored once and the occurrences are counted.
Edit: People are suggesting I use a map instead of an arrayList but my professor has required that I use an ArrayList.

Comment: Use ArrayList.contains() to figure out if an integer is in the list, and Integer.parseInt() to convert lines into integers. Refer to this question for info on reading from files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a place to dump your projects and let the community solve it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? You can't expect the community to solve the problem for you

Comment: Please post that in your actual question and format it correctly

Comment: What are your exact requirements? Do you _have_ to use an ArrayList, or can it be something more appropriate, such as a Map?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I am required to use an ArrayList to store the integers

Answer (score 3):

A couple things to note

1. Your `ArrayList` cannot be declared to hold an `int`. It can only work with objects, not primitives
2. `Scanner#nextLine` returns a `String`, not an `Integer`. You should instead use [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). Or, you could cast your `String` to an `Integer` by calling [`Integer#valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))
3. Your use of an `ArrayList` is questionable at this point. I suggest using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead. It is...

   > An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each   key can map to at most one value

Thus, your code can then look like this(the relationship is `number, # o/occurrences`):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
while (inputFile.hasNext()){
    Integer next = inputFile.nextInt();
    if (myMap.containsKey(next)){
        myMap.put(next, myMap.get(next) + 1);
    }else{
        myMap.put(next, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for the map suggestion.  this would have been my go-to answer as well.

Comment: unfortunately I am required to use an arrayList for this assignment, and cannot use a map. Thank you very much for your feedback though. I appreciate it!

Comment: You could still use a Map to store the occurrences of each number, while also adding the number to your ArrayList. But you might also consider using just a simple array of 101 ints holding the occurrences, which could be more space- and time- efficient than a Map.

Comment: piggybacking off of this answer you can use autoboxing to achieve your requirement of using an arrayList

Comment: Would it be considered cheating if you used the map, exactly as in Michael's answer, and then at the end you did `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(myMap.keySet());` ?